# Second Windows account with same credentials?

Tags: windows, user-accounts

I would like to have two accounts on my machine

- A work account with all my applications installed
- A present account to present things at conferences

I noticed I cannot create another account on the same PC that use the same account login as my primary account.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

> I noticed I cannot create another account on the same PC that uses the same account login as my primary account.

A Windows user account username must be unique.

> I would like to have two accounts on my machine
>
> - A work account with all my applications installed
> - A present account to present things at conferences
>
> Is there a way to do this?

There absolutely is not a way to have multiple accounts have the same username and password.  Even if you log into the machine with a Microsoft username there is an underline local account that is created.  **What you want is not possible.**  If you want two accounts to have the same password your welcome to do that though.